# Laptop battery won't charge

Tags: laptop, battery, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop, charging

I have an IBM ThinkPad Z61t that I've salvaged into a usable state, but the battery won't charge.  Its probably because one or more of the cells are dead, but I'm not entirely sure. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and this is a screenshot from the power statistics window.

[image: Power Statistics]]

Any help would be much appreciated, and if its possible to get this battery working again, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The design capacity is reported as 655.4 Wh, an abnormal value indicating battery failure.

655.4 Wh is most likely 655.35 Wh rounded to the nearest tenth. As no laptop battery has this much energy (most laptop batteries have less than 100 Wh of energy capacity), and since 65535 is 2<sup>16</sup> – 1, this indicates that the battery has failed. You'll need to replace the battery.

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark below the voting controls so that we know your problem is solved.

Comment: Oh okay I didn't know that was a thing thank you